# How to install Yocto on Beaglebone black´s Emmc using U-Boot

Tags: yocto, beagleboneblack, u-boot, openembedded

I build a Yocto console-image for Beaglebone Black and flash it into the SD Card. I can boot the Yocto on the beaglebone trow SD card. So goog so far. Now my question:

How can I flash the yocto to Beaglebone Black is internal EMMC using U-boot?

I spend one week try to find e test different way, but with out success. I can flash a Debian to the EMMC with succec but not  the yocto.

If you know a way to do that please give any advise with the step.

I thank you for help and information on this topic :-)

Best,

Steve

Step:

```
My current location is in :~/bbb/meta-bbb/scripts

sdd      8:48   1   3,6G  0 disk
├─sdd1   8:49   1    64M  0 part /media/steve/B22B-89B9
└─sdd2   8:50   1   3,6G  0 part /media/steve/ROOT

sudo ./mk2parts.sh sdd
export OETMP=/home/steve/bbb/build/tmp
cp emmc-uEnv.txt uEnv.txt
./copy_boot.sh sdd
./copy_rootfs.sh sdd installer
```

Comment: did you look at this [tutorial](https://jumpnowtek.com/beaglebone/BeagleBone-Systems-with-Yocto.html)?

Comment: Yes from this tutorial

Comment: Is there any error in u-boot?

Answer (score 1):

There are many steps to build an image with the Yocto Project and then flash it to the eMMC memory of the BeagleBone Black (BBB). I wrote the following guide that walks through the process in specific detail:

https://takeofftechnical.com/yocto-project-linux-bbb/

In a nutshell:

1. erase the eMMC
2. boot to the SD card
3. use dd to write the image from Yocto to the eMMC
4. power down
5. remove card
6. power up
7. verify success
8. expand root partition to utilize free space